# os.system not running inside for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data= pd.read_csv("ztf1.csv",usecols=[5],header=0)
#print(data)
names=data.columns

data1= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=names)
#print(data1)

for columnData in data1:
  os.system('wget --auth-no-challenge --user=xxxx@gmail.com --password=xxxx -O ztf.csv "https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/ZTF/nph_light_curves?ID={0}&FORMAT=CSV"'.format('oid'))
```

This is my code.It dosent even give any errors.Just no output.

Comment: Is data1 empty?

Comment: Why aren't you using `columnData` in the loop?

Comment: Maybe `format('oid')` should be `format(columnData['oid'])`?

Comment: no data1 is not empty,i checked it with the print statement

Comment: @Barmar format(columnData['oid']) gives string indices must be integers error

Comment: Use `for columnData in data1.itertuples():`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas